# how do I declare a matlab variable to store string?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

In this matlab code,

```
% kalimba memory read
clear all
clc
close all
read_val = zeros(128, 1);
read_val_INDEX = 1;
fid = fopen('kal_mem_data.txt', 'r');
% assume each row has 1 address string and 16 data strings
for j=1:8
    asd = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);  % skip the address string
    for i=1:16
        read_val(read_val_INDEX) = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);
        read_val_INDEX = read_val_INDEX + 1;
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

kal_mem_data.txt has a list of hexadecimal numbers as

```
0001c1 FF45DF 012345 ...
```

The first scanf works without problems

```
asd = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);
```

asd is automatically typecasted to char type to store the hex string as a character array
How do I predeclare an array read_val so that each element of read val is a string?
Is there an easy way to do this in matlab?

Comment: yes they are same length, 6 digit hexadecimal numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If all strings have the same length:**

You could preallocate a 128x6 matrix (assuming the string length is 6) like this:

```
read_val = char(zeros(128, 6, 'uint8'));
```

Then, you would read each string on a line, like this:

```
read_val(read_val_INDEX, :) = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);
```

**If the strings don't necessarily have the same length:**

One good approach would be using a cell array, like this:

```
read_val = cell(128, 1);
```

And you would read like this:

```
read_val{read_val_INDEX} = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);
```